# .NET Core Worker service does not have CRON

Tags: c#, .net-core, cron, backgroundworker

I'm working with .net core 3.1 worker service
The worker contains cron job with this Nuget package CronScheduler.Extensions v3.0.0
I completed project in my development env.(everything OK and No error) and im going to serve in production and install the worker with sc.exe
when i start the worker service something went wrong and i have a following error from the event viewer log

Category: CronScheduler.Extensions.Internal.SchedulerRegistration
EventId: 101

[Job][WasJob] does not have CRON: . Task will not run.

How can i fix this problem any idea?
Thanks for answers.

Comment: What OS do you have in you dev and prod environment?

Comment: both of win10 1809

Comment: How do you configure `SchedulerOptions`?  This error happens when the library can't find [SchedulerOptions.CronSchedule](https://github.com/kdcllc/CronScheduler.AspNetCore/blob/master/src/CronScheduler.Extensions/Internal/SchedulerRegistration.cs#L95)

Comment: @GuruStron Yes i check the appsettings.json and i think couldn't read(or found) it. Its look fixed. Thanks for answers

Comment: Will add this as an answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is an issue with settings. Check how do you configure `SchedulerOptions`. This error happens when the library can't find [`SchedulerOptions.CronSchedule`](https://github.com/kdcllc/CronScheduler.AspNetCore/blob/master/src/CronScheduler.Extensions/Internal/SchedulerRegistration.cs#L95).